# drush cannot find omega help commands

Tags: drush, theming

I've installed Omega 4 but drush cannot find the omega help set or the omega command set -- nor can I. Where are these supposed to be located? Without them, I cannot easily create a subtheme with drush, or do any of the drush goodies in omega 4.

Answer (score 3):

Drush can only find additional commands in themes and modules if it knows where your Drupal site is.  There are several ways you can do this; cd to the directory that contains your settings.php file, or pass --root and --uri on the commandline to point at the Drupal Root and site uri (e.g. mysite.com), or define a site alias and pass @alias on the command line.  See the Drush [README](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/README.md) file on the github project page for more information.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. The problem was that the documentation advised cd'ing to the Drupal root directory, not the directory containing the settings file. Because I had a multisite setup, this wouldn't work. Initially, I solved the problem by manually building an Omega 4 subtheme and cd'ing into it, after which drush found the omega help set.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem because I've placed my themes in profile folder, it works good If I move them back to sites/all/themes/